# I'm trying to create a bool function that evaluates a char and returns true if char is '(' ')' '*' '-' '+'

Tags: c++

I'm getting a warning code C682 and im newer to programming so I'm not sure exactly what is wrong.

```
bool isOperator(char ch)
{

    if (ch == '(' or ')' or '*' or '-' or '+')
    {
        return true;
    }
    else 
        return false;
}
```

I want it to return true if the char is one of those and false if it's something else.

Comment: return (ch == '(') || (ch== ')') || (ch == '*') || (ch == '-') || (ch == '+');

Comment: OK, an advice: *Don't try random things*. Why did you decide that this code would work? Which book/tutorial gave you that idea?  Learn the basics (there are plenty of materials out there), and then write a code you are absolutely confident in (you'll find out that even then it often doesn't work).

Comment: Provide full error message in addition to code number.

Comment: I know there is a duplicate of this question, but I can't find it.

Comment: This should be of use: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Lets go over a few things:
Replace or with the actual operator || in c++ which is equivalent to or. (Note that or is a ISO646 standard and can be used, but depends on preference)

Next we need to ensure ch is added for every character you are checking

After that we should have in a more simple form:

```
return (ch == '(') || (ch== ')') || (ch == '*') || (ch == '-') || (ch == '+');
```

Note: We can also do it the way you have by if/else

```
bool is_operator_match = false;
if (ch == '(') || (ch== ')') || (ch == '*') || (ch == '-') || (ch == '+')
{
    is_operator_match = true;
}

return is_operator_match;
```

Comment: Minor nitpick: "_Replace or with the actual operator || in c++_" Why? `or` is an [alternative representation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_alternative) of `||` operator. "_which is equivalent to or._" Hence, in fact, it is `or` that is equivalent to `||`.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius no it is not... Not all compilers support that and it is not part of the C++ standard. At least not that I have heard/seen. Reading the article I don't see it saying it is part of the standard, I don't think all compilers handle that.

Comment: "_Not all compilers support that and it is not part of the C++ standard._" Then why is it listed in C++ standard section 5.12 [lex.operators]?

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius, interesting, did not know it was part of the standard. Looks like it was originated from Standard C in 1995.

Comment: @OmidCompSCI Note that in C the alternative tokens are macros defined in a header, while in C++ they are keywords.

Comment: [It can be used interchangeably](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_logical).

Answer (score 3):

`or` is a logical operator in C++ so you need to put conditional operators:

```
 return ch == '(' or ch == ')' or ch == '*' or ch == '-' or ch == '+');
```

otherwise you evaluate `'c'` and others as an expression which is always `true`.

Some may see this more readabale (it is less repeatative):

```
bool isOperator(char ch)
{
    switch( ch ) {
       case '(' : 
       case ')' :
       case '*' :
       case '-' :
       case '+' :
           return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

or more C++ way (though it is more expensive but in your case of 5 variants unlikely to matter):

```
 bool isOperator(char ch)
 {
    const std::string_view ops( "()*-+" );
    return ops.find( ch ) != std::string_view::npos;
 }
```

Comment: And there is always [the `strchr` option](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strchr)

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you could implement it as a search into an array. This way you can add and remove operators easily.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

bool isOperator(char op) {
  const char operators[] = {'(', ')', '+', '-', '*'};

  return std::find(std::begin(operators), std::end(operators), op) != std::end(operators);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The right way to write it would be

```
if (ch == '(' or ch == ')' or ch == '*' or ch == '+')
```

---

In addition to the other answers here, you could use `std::any_of`:

```
bool isOperator(char ch)
{
  static const std::array arr { '(', ')', '*', '-', '+' };
  return std::any_of(arr.begin(), arr.end(), [ch](char const& c) {
    return ch == c;
  });
}
```